# Computer Vision/Image Processing Riddles

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, algorithms

I know this topic is not clearly relevant to the forum, but I think it's fun and interesting.

I'm looking for computer vision riddles - fun and interesting questions that have a clear and precise solution. For example the following: We have a binary image with paths (contours) that are one pixel wide. Come up with an algorithm to find the ends of the paths. I know of two solutions to this riddle.

Do you know of any other riddles? I'll be happy to hear some!

Thanks,

Gil.

Answer (score 1):

Nice idea :)

A few years ago, the Instagram team proposed the [Unshredder challenge](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12651721845/instagram-engineering-challenge-the-unshredder). The chalélenge is over now, but the game is still interesting and could be extended to more difficult puzzles.